# S3ObjectSummmary not able to call function

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, scala-java-interop

I am very new to scala I am trying to pull the list of files name given a bucket name in s3. Here are my code:

```
val basicCredentials = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey))
val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
  .withCredentials(basicCredentials)
  .build()
val res = s3.listObjects("myBucket").getObjectSummaries().toArray()
val filename = res.map(s3ObSummary => s3ObSummary.getKey())
```

The error is: value getKey is not a member of Object. Actually, I am using IntelliJ and the ide also says no method getKey for s3Obsummary.

The elements in the array are supposed to be  S3ObjectSummmary object but it is not able to call the function like getKey(). It must be a very simple issue but I didn't find where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is actually pretty simple.
It is in the [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--) part.
If you look at the **documentation**, it says it returns an `Array[AnyRef]` *(`Object[]` in Java)*. Thus, you lost it's type.

There are many solutions to this problem like:

1) Using `asIsntanceOf` *(not recommended!!!)*.

```
val filename = res.map(s3ObSummary => s3ObSummary.asIsntanceOf[S3ObjectSummary].getKey())
```

2) Using **pattern matching** together with `collect` *(the same as above but more safe)*.

```
val filename = res.collect { case s3ObSummary: S3ObjectSummary => s3ObSummary.getKey() }
```

3) Or, my personal preference, using [**JavaConverters**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html).

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._ // Provides the asScala extension method.

val basicCredentials = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey))
val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
  .withCredentials(basicCredentials)
  .build()

val res = s3.listObjects("myBucket").getObjectSummaries().asScala
val filename = res.map(s3ObSummary => s3ObSummary.getKey())
```

4) As @AlexeyRomanov suggested. Using the correct form of [`toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-).

```
val res = s3.listObjects("myBucket").getObjectSummaries().toArray(Array.empty[S3ObjectSummary])
```

Comment: Hi Luis,  Thanks for the elaboration. two questions here: 1. when I use toarray() then what type of element exactly in this array?  2. the first option you provided, why it is not safe?

Comment: @yabchexu the type of the Array is `AnyRef` in **Scala** or `Object` in **Java** _(which are the same)_, basically it is a top type, which is not too useful except for `toString` & `hashCode`. - `asInstanceOf` as well as the use of `null` _(which are pretty common in **Java**)_ are not recommended in **Scala**, because from the perspective of the type system are not safe. Particularly `asInstanceOf` is shutting down the compiler, you are basically saying _"You do not know what is this, but I do know. So, just shut up and obey me, I am smarter"_, well in simple cases you may be, but usually no.

Comment: _(**Disclaimer:** the above comment was meant as a joke, not intention of offending anyone)_. Now, being more serious, it is usually a bad idea to don't trust the compiler, specially when there are safer and simple ways to achieve the same, which is what the second example showed.

Comment: 4) using the correct version of `toArray`: `s3.listObjects("myBucket").getObjectSummaries().toArray(Array[S3ObjectSummary]())`